# Unable to publish files in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

When I publish a file from code

```
byte[] fileBytes = objItem.File.OpenBinary();
string DestinationURL = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", objDestinationFolder.Url, objItem.File.Name);

//Copy the file.
SPFile objDestinationFile = objDestinationFolder.Files.Add(DestinationURL, fileBytes, true);
objDestinationFile.Update();
objDestinationFile.Publish(string.Format("File Copied from {0}", objItem.Url));
```

I get an error message which says

```
 You can only publish, unpublish  documents in a minor version enabled list
```

I checked the permissions of the list and it has "Create major and minor (draft) versions" checked. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

If I check in the file by calling the CheckIn method

```
objDestinationFile.CheckIn(string.Format(@"File Copied from {0}/{1}", objItem.Web.Url, objItem.Url));
```

everything works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a file has to be checked in first, and then it can be published.

So in your case it might be possible, that in the settings of your list 'checkout required' is activated. Which means that if you upload a document, it is checked out first.

Comment: Yes, I had to check it in but I found out that I didn't need to publish.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error even though minor versions were enabled on the library. The reason was I had added a draft file to a module without the `Type="GhostableInLibrary"` attribute. Once I corrected this the draft file could be published by my feature receiver.